# Python requests web scraping API

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have some experience with web scraping and API, however I'm not able to search the proper API do to do so in this website:

https://www.giga.com.vc/Bebida
obs: /Bebida is just a category like "/Drinks"

The issue is, I found several APIs but they are for one product only, or they even are for some products, but I can't seem to find the right rules to paginate it with proper categories or pages and iterate through category products getting prices, EANS etc.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Ex: This works, but the format is horrible:

```
print(requests.get('https://www.giga.com.vc/padaria?initialMap=c&initialQuery=padaria&map=category-1&page=1').content)
```

or

```
urlx = 'https://www.giga.com.vc/_v/segment/graphql/v1?workspace=master&maxAge=short&appsEtag=remove&domain=store&locale=pt-BR&operationName=Products&variables=%7B%7D&extensions=%7B%22persistedQuery%22%3A%7B%22version%22%3A1%2C%22sha256Hash%22%3A%2249a77e3e2082563773aff56ad9c0432d59302e86fd1baaad9ca0f4bca2630d46%22%2C%22sender%22%3A%22vtex.store-resources%400.x%22%2C%22provider%22%3A%22vtex.search-graphql%400.x%22%7D%2C%22variables%22%3A%22eyJoaWRlVW5hdmFpbGFibGVJdGVtcyI6ZmFsc2UsInNrdXNGaWx0ZXIiOiJBTExfQVZBSUxBQkxFIiwiaW5zdGFsbG1lbnRDcml0ZXJpYSI6Ik1BWF9XSVRIT1VUX0lOVEVSRVNUIiwiY2F0ZWdvcnkiOiIiLCJjb2xsZWN0aW9uIjoiMTYvIiwic3BlY2lmaWNhdGlvbkZpbHRlcnMiOltdLCJvcmRlckJ5IjoiIiwiZnJvbSI6MCwidG8iOjExfQ%3D%3D%22%7D'
r = requests.get(urlx)
for x in r.json()['data']['products']:
    print(x)
```

As well this also works:

```
url2 = 'https://www.giga.com.vc/_v/segment/graphql/v1?workspace=master&maxAge=short&appsEtag=remove&domain=store&locale=pt-BR&__bindingId=3f6e91e6-44f2-4fb0-a2d9-e238b53082e0&operationName=ProductRecommendations&variables=%7B%7D&extensions=%7B%22persistedQuery%22%3A%7B%22version%22%3A1%2C%22sha256Hash%22%3A%22e5782bd9e8bc64d337a7d7f96b9c280b462cdb0754d15b415192dac2755ad280%22%2C%22sender%22%3A%22vtex.shelf%401.x%22%2C%22provider%22%3A%22vtex.search-graphql%400.x%22%7D%2C%22variables%22%3A%22eyJpZGVudGlmaWVyIjp7ImZpZWxkIjoiaWQiLCJ2YWx1ZSI6IjE0NzUyMyJ9LCJ0eXBlIjoidmlldyJ9%22%7D'

requests.get(url2).json()['data']['productRecommendations']
```

Expected output something like this:

```
r = requests.get(urlx)
for items in r.json()['data']['products']:
    prd_dict = {
        'product_id': items['productId'],
        'price': items['priceRange']['sellingPrice']['highPrice'],
        'product_name': items['productName'],
        'category_id': items['categoryId'],
        'ean': items['items'][0]['ean'],
        'box_qty': items['specificationGroups'][0]['specifications'][0]['values']
        }
    print(prd_dict)
```

raw output:

```
{'product_id': '141917', 'price': 20.54, 'product_name': 'Banana Nanica Kg', 'category_id': '433', 'ean': '4511', 'box_qty': ['0']}
{'product_id': '148077', 'price': 1.45, 'product_name': 'Água de Coco Tradicional Quadrado 200Ml', 'category_id': '148', 'ean': '0751320333650', 'box_qty': ['27']}
```

Comment: the api looks like graphql api. can you clearly define what's expected, e.g. provide some observable criteria?

Comment: Just updated the output :)

Comment: it sends `variables` in `base64` which decoded have `'{"hideUnavailableItems":false,"skusFilter":"ALL","simulationBehavior":"default","installmentCriteria":"MAX_WITHOUT_INTEREST","productOriginVtex":false,"map":"c","query":"bebida","orderBy":"OrderByScoreDESC","from":40,"to":59,"selectedFacets":[{"key":"c","value":"bebida"}],"operator":"and","fuzzy":"0","searchState":null,"facetsBehavior":"Static","categoryTreeBehavior":"default","withFacets":false}'`

Comment: and there is `"from":40,"to":59` which gives 20 values - and page loads 20 items when you click button.

Comment: @furas Thanks for your explanation!
Some thoughts for decoding this automatically?
I mean, how you did that?

Comment: I tested it manually - I cut off text after `variables` - `text = "eyJoaWRlVW5hdmFp...."` and use `base64.b64decode( text.encode() ).decode()`

Comment: Last thing, as dont have much experience with this encoded stuff: Is that possible to build a request using this "decode format" above as "body/payload"?

Comment: you may need to convert back to `base64` and put in correct place. I hope it doesn't use some other value as "control sum"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sends `variables` as `base64` which after decoding have

```
'{"hideUnavailableItems":false,"skusFilter":"ALL","simulationBehavior":"default","installmentCriteria":"MAX_WITHOUT_INTEREST","productOriginVtex":false,"map":"c","query":"bebida","orderBy":"OrderByScoreDESC","from":40,"to":59,"selectedFacets":[{"key":"c","value":"bebida"}],"operator":"and","fuzzy":"0","searchState":null,"facetsBehavior":"Static","categoryTreeBehavior":"default","withFacets":false}'
```

If I parse URL, convert all to dictiorany, replace with `'from': 0`
`'to': 99` then I get 100 products

But it doesn't work if U use value bigger then 99. Maybe it would need some other changes in URL.

```
import base64
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request
import json

url1 = 'https://www.giga.com.vc/_v/segment/graphql/v1?workspace=master&maxAge=short&appsEtag=remove&domain=store&locale=pt-BR&__bindingId=3f6e91e6-44f2-4fb0-a2d9-e238b53082e0&operationName=productSearchV3&variables=%7B%7D&extensions=%7B%22persistedQuery%22%3A%7B%22version%22%3A1%2C%22sha256Hash%22%3A%226869499be99f20964918e2fe0d1166fdf6c006b1766085db9e5a6bc7c4b957e5%22%2C%22sender%22%3A%22vtex.store-resources%400.x%22%2C%22provider%22%3A%22vtex.search-graphql%400.x%22%7D%2C%22variables%22%3A%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%22%7D'
url2 = 'https://www.giga.com.vc/_v/segment/graphql/v1?workspace=master&maxAge=short&appsEtag=remove&domain=store&locale=pt-BR&__bindingId=3f6e91e6-44f2-4fb0-a2d9-e238b53082e0&operationName=productSearchV3&variables=%7B%7D&extensions=%7B%22persistedQuery%22%3A%7B%22version%22%3A1%2C%22sha256Hash%22%3A%226869499be99f20964918e2fe0d1166fdf6c006b1766085db9e5a6bc7c4b957e5%22%2C%22sender%22%3A%22vtex.store-resources%400.x%22%2C%22provider%22%3A%22vtex.search-graphql%400.x%22%7D%2C%22variables%22%3A%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%22%7D'

#print('--- url ---')
#print(url)

parts = urllib.parse.urlparse(url1)
#print(parts)

query = urllib.parse.parse_qs(parts.query)
#print(query)

data = json.loads(query['extensions'][0])
variables = data['variables']
#print(variables)

q = base64.b64decode(variables.encode()).decode()
q = json.loads(q)

print('--- replace values ---')

print(q)

q['from'] = 0
q['to'] = 99

print(q)

print('---')

q = json.dumps(q)
variables = base64.b64encode(q.encode()).decode()
#print(variables)

data['variables'] = variables
query['extensions'][0] = json.dumps(data)
#print(query)

parts = parts._replace(query=urllib.parse.urlencode(query, doseq=True))
#print(parts)

url = urllib.parse.urlunparse(parts)
#print('--- url ---')
#print(url)


req = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
data = json.loads(req.read())
for number, item in enumerate(data['data']['productSearch']['products'], 1):
    print(number, '|', item['productName'])
```

Result:

```
1 | Água de Coco Tradicional Quadrado 200Ml
2 | Leite Longa Vida Integral com Tampa Italac 1L
3 | Leite Longa Vida Quatá  Integral 1L
4 | Água Mineral sem Gás Minalba 1,5L
5 | Água Mineral Sem Gás Minalba 510Ml
6 | Refrigerante Coca-Cola200Ml
7 | Leite Longa Vida Integral Shefa Garrafa 1L
8 | Refrigerante Coca-Cola sem Açúcar 1L
9 | Cerveja Heineken Lata 350Ml
10 | Leite Integral Longa Vida com Tampa Ninho 1L
11 | Leite Longa Vida Semidesnatado Com Tampa Italac 1L
12 | Cerveja Heineken Long Neck 330Ml
13 | Cerveja Amstel Lata 269Ml
14 | Água Mineral Minalba Com Gás 510Ml
15 | Água Mineral Pureza Vital Sem Gás Nestlé Pet 510Ml
16 | Água Mineral Sem Gás Bonafont 500Ml
17 | Refrigerante Coca-Cola sem Açúcar 200ml
18 | Água de Coco Kero Coco 1L
19 | Refrigerante Coca-Cola 2,5L
20 | Leite Longa Vida Desnatado com Tampa Italac 1L
21 | Refrigerante Coca-Cola Lata 350Ml
22 | Leite Longa Vida Integral Tirol 1L
23 | Água Mineral com Gás Pureza Vital 510ML
24 | Suco de Uva Integral Tinto Aurora 1,5L
25 | Achocolatado Toddynho 200Ml
26 | Refrigerante Coca-Cola sem Açúcar Lata 220ml
27 | Energético Red Bull Energy Drink 250Ml
28 | Água Mineral Sem Gás Pureza Vital Nestlé 1,5 L
29 | Suco Natural One Laranja 2L
30 | Refrigerante Coca-Cola 2L
31 | Cerveja Skol Lata 350Ml
32 | Refrigerante Coca-Cola 1L
33 | Suco De Maçã Yakult 200Ml
34 | Cerveja Império Puro Malte Lata 269Ml
35 | Refrigerante Guaraná Antarctica 2L
36 | Refrigerante Coca-Cola Lata 220Ml
37 | Leite Em Pó Integral Italac Sachê 400G
38 | Água Coco Puro Coco 200Ml
39 | Água Mineral Com Gás Crystal Pet 1,5 L
40 | Achocolatado sabor Chocolate Italakinho  200Ml
41 | Cerveja Duplo Malte Brahma Lata 350Ml
42 | Água Mineral Indaiá sem Gás 500Ml
43 | Refresco em Pó Sabor Laranja Tang 25G
44 | Água De Coco Puro Coco 1L
45 | Cerveja Budweiser Lata 269Ml
46 | Cerveja Skol Lata 269Ml
47 | Refresco em Pó Sabor Uva Tang 25G
48 | Refrigerante Guaraná Antarctica Lata 350Ml
49 | Cerveja Eisenbahn Pilsen Lata 350Ml
50 | Cerveja Itaipava Lata 350Ml
51 | Cerveja Itaipava Lata 269Ml
52 | Refrigerante Coca-Cola 600Ml
53 | Refrigerante Guaraná Antarctica 1,5L
54 | Cerveja Stella Artois Lata 269Ml
55 | Whisky Escocês Johnnie Walker Red Label 1L
56 | Refrigerante Coca-Cola sem Açúcar 2L
57 | Água Mineral sem Gás Crystal Pet 1,5 L
58 | Cerveja Amstel Lata 350Ml
59 | Cerveja Corona Extra Long Neck 330Ml
60 | Cerveja Stella Artois Long Neck 330Ml
61 | Água Mineral Sem Gás Bonafont 1,5 L
62 | Cerveja Puro Malte Petra Lata 350Ml
63 | Água de Coco Kero Coco 200Ml
64 | Cerveja Heineken Garrafa 600Ml
65 | Refrigerante de Laranja Sukita 2L
66 | Chopp De Vinho Draft 600Ml
67 | Refrigerante De Limão H2Oh! 500Ml
68 | Suco Natural de Uva e Maca One Ambiente 2L
69 | Refrigerante Dolly Guaraná 2L
70 | Energético Energy Monster Lata 473Ml
71 | Refresco em Pó Sabor Limão Tang 25g
72 | Suco De Laranja Integral Prat's 4 Ls
73 | Energético Red Bull Tropical Energy Drink  250Ml
74 | Refrigerante Limoneto H2Oh! Pet 500Ml
75 | Água Tônica Antarctica Zero 350Ml
76 | Água Mineral Sem Gás Minalba 10 Ls
77 | Vodka Red Smirnoff 998Ml
78 | Suco De Laranja Natural Xandô Garrafa 900Ml
79 | Energético Red Bull Melancia Energy Drink 250Ml
80 | Bebida Láctea de Proteína Zero Lactose sabor Chocolate YoPro 15G
81 | Água Verão Sense Lindoya 510ml
82 | Vodka Nacional Smirnoff Ice Red 269ml
83 | Whisky Escocês White Horse 8 Anos 1L
84 | Refrigerante Coca-Cola sem Açúcar 2,5L
85 | Refresco em Pó Sabor Maracujá Tang 25g
86 | Cerveja Império Puro Malte Lata 350Ml
87 | Vodka Ice Smirnoff 275Ml
88 | Cerveja Eisenbahn Pilsen Long Neck 355Ml
89 | Guaraná Com Açaí Natural Guaraviton Pet 500Ml
90 | Cerveja Budweiser Long Neck 330Ml
91 | Água Mineral Com Gás Pet Crystal 500Ml
92 | Água Tônica Antarctica Lata 350Ml
93 | Refrigerante Sabor Guaraná Mini Dolly Pet 350Ml
94 | Água Tônica Schweppes lata 350ml
95 | Cachaça 51 965Ml
96 | Cerveja Skol Lata 550Ml
97 | Refresco em Pó Sabor Abacaxi Tang 25g
98 | Cerveja Puro Malte Petra Lata 269Ml
99 | Cachaça Velho Barreiro 910Ml
100 | Refrigerante Fanta Laranja 2L
```

Comment: Thank you very much, really helped :)

I'm just a bit confused because even paginating an error prompts as "urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 414: Request-URI Too Large" no matter if the payload is with packs of 0-20 itens or 0-99, as soon as I call api for the second iteration it raises this error.

Comment: as I remeber url with all arguments in GET request can't be longer then ~250 chars. If you get error then you have too long URL and something wrong is in URL. I had no problem with code which you see in answer so I have no idea what can be the problem.

Comment: Your code is working fine!
Just long requests are the problem, I'm doing a workaround here for these requests.

Anyway, thanks for everything :)